# NSOutlineView leaks memory. What to do?

Tags: swift, macos, memory-leaks, nsoutlineview

When a minimal OSX application that has nothing else but a plain (unconfigured) `NSOutlineView` in its storyboard, it will heavily leak memory.

### View controller implementation

The view controller is implemented as following:

```swift
import Cocoa

class Section {
    let title: String
    let items: [String]

    init(title: String, items: [String]) {
        self.title = title
        self.items = items
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate {

    //MARK: NSOutlineViewDataSource

    let items = [
        Section(title: "Alpha", items: ["Anton",  "Anita"]),
        Section(title: "Beta",  items: ["Bernd",  "Barbara"]),
        Section(title: "Gamma", items: ["Gustav", "Gesine"])]

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int {
        switch item {
        case nil:        return items.count
        case is Section: return (item as! Section).items.count
        default:         return 0
        }
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject {
        return item == nil
            ? items[index]
            : (item as! Section).items[index]
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return item is Section
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, byItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        return item
    }

    //MARK: NSOutlineViewDelegate

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: AnyObject) -> NSView? {
        let view = outlineView.makeViewWithIdentifier(item is Section ? "HeaderCell" : "DataCell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        view.textField?.stringValue = item is Section
            ? (item as! Section).title
            : item as! String
        return view
    }
}
```

[The Xcode project can be cloned from github](https://github.com/larsblumberg/nsoutlineview-memory-leak)

### Xcode showing a constantly increasing memory consumption

When the app is started and tree items are selected by clicking them, the memory consumption increases tremendously.

Xcode's debug navigator shows an increasing memory consumption over a short time. Memory increases only when you navigate through the NSOutlineView nodes.

[image: Xcode's debug navigator showing increasing memory consumption]

### Instruments not showing something suspicious (or does it?)

Instruments however is showing a constant memory usage, that is neither increasing nor decreasing:

[image: Instruments showing no leaks]

[image: Instruments' call tree statistics]

What can I conclude from Instrument's report? Is it not detecting leaks because it's `NSOutlineView` itself whose leaking (and those can't be detected?) or is there simply no leak at the end?

Comment: Did you profile your application using Instrument's Allocations? If you do that you should be able to pin-point the method that's consuming the most memory.

Comment: I've added screenshots of the memory consumption – both reported by Xcode's debug view and by Instruments. With strange results! What can I conclude from here?

Comment: I've added a link to the github repository containing the demo app (https://github.com/larsblumberg/nsoutlineview-memory-leak)